# How can we detect if a windows service is deleted,is there an event log id for it?

Tags: windows, services, event-log

Someone deleted a windows service, how can we detect it? Is there an event id related this action?

Comment: I'm sure someone can easily create one and then remove and check event log to see what it logs if anything. I would think it would for such an operation but don't have time to test this for you. Maybe an idea for someone to try unless they already know the answer.

Comment: And if it's not a regularly logged action, then certainly audit logging would capture this action (if enabled).

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/q/290299/213131) might help if one wants to create a service from any 'ol .EXE then turn around and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it would seem Service deletions are not logged in the same way as creations.

I ran:

```
sc create DummySvc binPath="C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe"
sc delete DummySvc
```

The System Event Log recorded Event ID 7045 on creation:

```
A service was installed in the system.

Service Name:  DummySvc
Service File Name:  C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe
Service Type:  user mode service
Service Start Type:  demand start
Service Account:  LocalSystem
```

But no similar events were recorded there on deletion.

Answer (score 1):

```
sc query [servicename]
```

returns `%errorcode%` 0 for an installed service and 1060 if the service doesn't exist.

If you don't want a user deleting a service you need to remove the privilege from the user.